# Alt keypresses not reaching IntelliJ

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, intellij

I've just installed Ubuntu 17.10, with GNOME. After installing IntelliJ (Ultimate) and starting to work on a project, I noticed the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut was just inserting a newline. No problem, I thought, I would just change the keybind to be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>! Alas, the IntelliJ keybind manager won't detect me pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I did some Googling and found some reference to GNOME binding to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but it was many years ago and the suggested setting to fix it no longer seems to exist.